# Build failure with Parallelism in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I ran the build but failing with below errors. I have corrected the code but not sure what is the cause for this.

[image]

[image]

And Every time I have chosen Agent specification VS2017-Win 2016 but it is taking different one it seems after I noticed build was run. why it happening. Please help.

[image]

It is ASP.NET build.

Comment: Please add the error messages as text, not images. That way they can be found by search indexers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently Microsoft has been battling Bitcoin miners on their pipelines platform. To combat this, they've added additional validation to ensure you are you and your intent isn't nefarious.

They've taken away all the free pipelines from accounts by default and you need to fill in a form to contact support to get these pipelines reinstated.

The link to the form is in the red error message that is rendered in your build log.

Comment: I have already submitted that form your are referring, How long it would take to get reflected?

Comment: In my experience max 3 working days.

Comment: Hi Jessehouwing, It is resolved now after 3 days provided project has to be private and free and parallel it should free. MS confirmed adding it in the backend. Thank you for your input.